# How to use next/image for backgroundImage for a div block

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am using `nextjs`. I want use `next/image` for my background Image for a div. I saw several answers but everyone posting for full screen background image using `next/image` and not for a single div background image. I got this https://uharston.medium.com/next-js-image-optimization-on-background-images-65de18ea03f5. But its for full screen. I can use normal background Image but its not optimized like next/image.

Here's the Code i tried:

```
import Image from 'next/image'

export default function Home() {

  const imgURL = "https://i.postimg.cc/kXb4L4hB/abstract-blur-empty-green-gradient-studio-well-use-as-backgroundwebsite-templateframebusiness-report.jpg"

  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "black", height: "100vh" }}>
      <h1 style={{ color: "white", textAlign: "center" }}>Home Page </h1>

      {/* Background Image */}
      <div style={{ height: "500px", position: "relative" }}>
        <Image
          alt="main"
          src={imgURL}
          fill
          style={{ objectFit: "cover", objectPosition: "center" }}
          quality={100}
        />
      </div>

      {/* Content should come over image */}
      <div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center", flexDirection: "column" }}>
        <h3 style={{ color: "white" }}>Welcome Home</h3>
        <h4 style={{ color: "white" }}>Tom</h4>
      </div>

    </div>
  )
}
```

I need like this,
[image]

But I am getting this
[image]

I want the `Welcome Home and Tom Text` to be over the image. Please help me with some solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the image as background of the div like this :

```
<div style={{
  height: "500px", 
  position: "relative", 
  backgroundImage: `url(${imgURL})`,
  backgroundSize: "cover", 
  backgroundPosition: "center"
}}>
```

Or with `next/Image` :

```
<div style={{
  height: "500px", 
  position: "relative"
}}>
  <Image
    alt="main"
    src={imgURL}
    fill
    quality={100}
  />
  <div style={{
    position: "absolute",
    top: "50%",
    left: "50%",
    transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
    color: "white",
    textAlign: "center"
  }}>
    <h3>Welcome Home</h3>
    <h4>Tom</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: May I know How you put text over that image.

Comment: Then you can set the div with your text to absolute, and center it with CSS on the div. Want an example ?

Comment: Yes.. Want an example